# COLLADA export tangent and binormal

Tags: export, normals, collada

Is it supported with the latest version of Blender? If so, how do I get the tangent and binormal information exported?

I did find a "roadmap" of sorts for the COLLADA exporter feature in Blender *2.5*, and it does mention the binormal and tangent. I haven't found a similar roadmap or feature list however for the newest version. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Architecture/COLLADA#Roadmap_.26_TODO

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!